# How to GetChecked values and Remove unchecked in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox, partial-views

i use array for checkbox value,
if i click on checkbox it gets values,and if i uncheck this checkbox it remove its value and not save in array,here is my Code..

```
function selectUser(sender) {
        if (sender.prop('checked'),true)
            assignedTo[assignedTo.length] = sender.id;   
        else {
            for (var i = 0; i < assignedTo.length; i++) {
                if (sender.id == assignedTo[i]) {
                    assignedTo.splice(i, 1);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now My issue is if checked it saves value and if i uncheck it did not remove value from array,any help

Comment: Please provide the corresponding HTML or create a jsfiddle to demonstrate what's not working.

Comment: Why not just use `.push()` and `.pop()` to add and remove values from the array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The approach you've taken could be very tedious. You could use `.map()` you can re-evaluate the array every time a checkbox is checked or unchecked as follows:

```js
$(':checkbox[name=test]').on('change', function() {
    var assignedTo = $(':checkbox[name=test]:checked').map(function() {
        return this.id;
    })
    .get();

    //Out for DEMO purposes only 
    $('pre.out').text( JSON.stringify( assignedTo ) );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="test" value="1" id="c1"/> 1 <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="test" value="2" id="c2"/> 2 <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="test" value="3" id="c3"/> 3 <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="test" value="4" id="c4"/> 4 <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="test" value="5" id="c5"/> 5 <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="test" value="6" id="c6"/> 6 <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="test" value="7" id="c7"/> 7 <br/>

<!--output area for DEMO purposes only -->
<pre class="out"></pre>
```

Answer (score 6):

why not clear the array and store it with new values

```
var values=[];

$(".cbx").click(function(){
    values=[];
    $(".cbx").each(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked"))
            values.push($(this).val());
    });
    alert(values);
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/usjr4gme/)

or

```
var values=[];

$(".cbx").change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked"))
       values.push($(this).val());
    else{
       var x = values.indexOf($(this).val());
       values.splice(x,1);
    }
    alert(values);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Exactly what I was looking for.